# Algo- Given a sequence of memory access, give the minimum number of cache misses

Tags: algorithm, caching

Given inputs are: size of cache `s`, number of memory entries `n`, and a series of memory accesses.

Give the minumum number of cache misses possible.

Example:

s = 3, n = 4
1 2 3 1 4 1 2 3
min_miss = 4

I've been stuck the entire day. Thanks in advance!

You get to decide whatever behaviour the cache takes. You don't have to take in an entry even if it's accessed, for example. And it need not be regular. You don't need to follow a fixed "rule" to cache.

Comment: What type of cache? Lru, weighted? Ie how is the victim for eviction chosen, or is this what you are trying to work out?

Comment: You get to decide whatever behaviour the cache takes. You don't have to take in an entry even if it's accessed, for example.

Comment: And it need not be regular. You don't need to follow a fixed "rule" to cache.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try following http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_replacement_algorithm#The_theoretically_optimal_page_replacement_algorithm - when you need to swap something out swap out the item that will not be used again for the longest possible time. Since you get the entire sequence of memory accesses ahead of time this is feasible for you. This is obviously locally optimum at least up to the first cache miss after the cache becomes full, because every other strategy has had at least one cache miss by then. It is not obvious to me that this is globally optimal - searching I find a proof at http://www.stanford.edu/~bvr/psfiles/paging.pdf with a claim that other proofs of its optimality do exist but are even longer.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I read the article and about to implement it to test against sample inputs. I will update soon.